# Varias tablas en un registro con JOIN consulta SQL

Tags: php, mysqli, phpmyadmin

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
El problema viene aquí en la consulta y el bucle al mostrar los registros.
Fichamaterial crea el autonumerico PK y en las demás lo recojo de esta misma.
Dependiendo de la categoria del material muestro un desplegable u otro con datos de otra tabla las cuales tienen el mismo id.
El bucle me recorre todas las tablas y me crea todos los registros.
¿Que he de hacer en la consulta?

```html
       <?php
   include("Conexion.php");
 //creamos la consulta
   $sql="SELECT f.*,
   /*En el caso de cada categoria renombramos su campo para que todos salgan bajo un mismo nombre en este caso (m1)*/
   CASE 
   WHEN(f.categoria='ordenador') THEN o.placa
   WHEN(f.categoria='monitor') THEN m.tipom
   WHEN(f.categoria='impresora') THEN i.tipoi
   END as m1,
   /*Aplica lo mismo que el anterior para (m2)*/
   CASE 
   WHEN(f.categoria='ordenador') THEN o.procesador
   WHEN(f.categoria='monitor') THEN m.tamano
   WHEN(f.categoria='impresora') THEN i.consumible
   END as m2,
   /*En el caso de monitores e impresoras no tienen los otros campos, asi que devolvemos una cadena vacia y en el caso del ordenado el campo de la ram*/
   CASE 
   WHEN(f.categoria='ordenador') THEN o.ram
   WHEN(f.categoria='monitor') THEN ''
   WHEN(f.categoria='impresora') THEN ''
   END as m3,
   /*Aplica lo mismo del caso anterior ahora devolvemos el campo de disco*/
   CASE 
   WHEN(f.categoria='ordenador') THEN o.disco
   WHEN(f.categoria='monitor') THEN ''
   WHEN(f.categoria='impresora') THEN ''
   END as m4,
   /*Añado*/
   CASE 
   WHEN(f.categoria='ordenador') THEN o.tarjetas
   WHEN(f.categoria='monitor') THEN ''
   WHEN(f.categoria='impresora') THEN ''
   END as m5,

   CASE 
   WHEN(f.categoria='ordenador') THEN o.ip
   WHEN(f.categoria='monitor') THEN ''
   WHEN(f.categoria='impresora') THEN ''
   END as m6,

   CASE 
   WHEN(f.categoria='ordenador') THEN o.dominio
   WHEN(f.categoria='monitor') THEN ''
   WHEN(f.categoria='impresora') THEN ''
   END as m7,

   CASE 
   WHEN(f.categoria='ordenador') THEN o.software
   WHEN(f.categoria='monitor') THEN ''
   WHEN(f.categoria='impresora') THEN ''
   END as m8

   FROM
   fichamaterial AS f
/*La sentencia LEF OUTER JOIN Busca el registro, si lo encuentra lo devuelve y si no toma valor vacio, en este caso condicionamos el JOIN de la siguiente forma
 1- Si la categoria del equipo es ordenador, entonces el JOIN sera entre fichamaterial y ordenadores, en caso negativo se devuelve NULL esto signifca que no hará join
 2- Si la categoria del equipo es monitor, entonces el JOIN sera entre fichamaterial y monitores, en caso negativo se devuelve NULL esto signifca que no hará join
 3- Si la categoria del equipo es impresora, entonces el JOIN sera entre fichamaterial e impresoras, en caso negativo se devuelve NULL esto signifca que no hará join
*/
 LEFT OUTER JOIN ordenadores AS o ON f.idreferencia=(CASE WHEN f.categoria='ordenador' THEN o.idreferencia ELSE NULL END)
 LEFT OUTER JOIN monitores AS m ON f.idreferencia=(CASE WHEN f.categoria='monitor' THEN m.idreferencia ELSE NULL END) 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN impresoras AS i ON f.idreferencia=(CASE WHEN f.categoria='impresora' THEN i.idreferencia ELSE NULL END);";
 //ejecutamos la consulta
 $registros=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
 //leemos el contenido de $registros
 while ($linea=mysqli_fetch_array($registros))
 {
  $elemento='td'.$linea['categoria'].$linea['idreferencia'];
  echo "<tr>
  <td>$linea[idreferencia]<br><input type='button' value='Ver' onclick='show($elemento.id)'></td>
  <td>$linea[aparato]</td>
  <td>$linea[categoria]</td>
  <td>$linea[proveedor]</td>
  <td>$linea[marca]</td>
  <td>$linea[modelo]</td>
  <td>$linea[nserie]</td>
  <td>$linea[fechaentrada]</td>
  <td>$linea[cantidad]</td>
  <td>$linea[autorizadapor]</td>
  <td>$linea[garantia]</td>
  <td>$linea[ubicacion]</td>
  <td>$linea[ninterno]</td>
  <td>$linea[fechabaja]</td>
  <td>$linea[observaciones]</td>
 </tr>";
 if ($linea['categoria']=='ordenador') {
  echo "<tr id='tdordenador$linea[idreferencia]' style='display: none;'>
  <td>$linea[idreferencia]<br>Specs:</td>
  <td>Placa:<br>$linea[m1]</td>
  <td>Procesador:<br>$linea[m2]</td>
  <td>Ram:<br>$linea[m3]</td>
  <td>Disco:<br>$linea[m4]</td>
  <td>Tarjetas:<br>$linea[m5]</td>
  <td>Ip:<br>$linea[m6]</td>
  <td>Dominio:<br>$linea[m7]</td>
  <td>Software:<br>$linea[m8]</td>
 </tr>";
}
if ($linea['categoria']=='monitor') {
echo "<tr id='tdmonitor$linea[idreferencia]' style='display: none;'>
<td>$linea[idreferencia]<br>Specs:</td>
<td>Tipo:<br>$linea[m1]</td>
<td>Tamaño:<br>$linea[m2]</td>
</tr>";
}
if ($linea['categoria']=='impresora') {
echo "<tr id='tdimpresora$linea[idreferencia]' style='display: none;'>
<td>$linea[idreferencia]<br>Specs:</td>
<td>Tipo:<br>$linea[m1]</td>
<td>Consumible:<br>$linea[m2]</td>
</tr>";
}
}
mysqli_close($conexion);
?>
```

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que pretendes hacer con tu consulta? Exactamente qué información es la que quieres mostrar

Comment: Entiendo que tu where debería ser algo como **f.idreferencia=o.idreferencia Or f.idreferencia=m.idreferencia Or f.idreferencia=i.idreferencia**. En cualquier caso la consulta no creo que te devuelva lo que quieres.  Además la tabla va a quedar un poco rara porque no tiene siempre el mismo tamaño de registro

Comment: **El problema** viene de que aún no has entendido del todo lo de **las consultas preparadas**, una forma de construirlas es usando el signo de interrogación `?`, como se ve que pretendes hacer aquí: `...WHERE ?`, significa que luego debes pasar por parámetro (binding) los valores que sustituirán cada símbolo `?` en la instrucción SQL. Afirmo que hay un problema de comprensión de las consultas preparadas porque en los `INSERT INTO` de arriba **no las usas**, lo cual hace tu código totalmente vulnerable a la **Inyección SQL** Sugiero que [leas esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/18232/29967)

Comment: @Lixus pretendo recuperar dos registros de la tabla a y de la tabla b los cuales tienen el mismo id y que quede ab, he añadido una imagen con la traza.

Comment: @AngelCid he añadido una imagen para intentar explicarlo, investigando creo que lo que busco es alguna clausula join pero no estoy seguro, la clausala where f.idreferencia=o.idreferencia Or f.idreferencia=m.idreferencia Or f.idreferencia=i.idreferencia si la tengo clara

Comment: @A.Cedano el signo de interrogación era para expresar duda, la inyección de momento no me preocupa, es un proyecto para clase, pero gracias!

Comment: Lo analizé de otra manera y creo que lo que quieres está bien complejo, ya que si es un ordenador habrá que hacer join con la tabla ordenadores, si es una impresora join con la tabla impresoras, es un join condicional

Comment: @AquilesPerez estuve amoldandolo a mi tabla y es perfectamente funcional, he editado el post con el codigo final, un abrazo y gracias por tu tiempo, es un proyecto para clase y cada vez estoy aprendiendo mas sql gracias a gente como tu!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola estoy usando la siguiente estructura para probar, no están validadas las relaciones porque no es ese el objetivo, dejo el script para que veas que funciona.

1-Script de prueba.

```
-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for fichamaterial
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `fichamaterial`;
CREATE TABLE `fichamaterial` (
  `idreferencia` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `categoria` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `marca` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idreferencia`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of fichamaterial
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `fichamaterial` VALUES ('1', 'impresora', 'HP');
INSERT INTO `fichamaterial` VALUES ('2', 'ordenador', 'DELL');
INSERT INTO `fichamaterial` VALUES ('3', 'monitor', 'Samsung');

-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for impresoras
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `impresoras`;
CREATE TABLE `impresoras` (
  `idreferencia` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tipol` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `consumible` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of impresoras
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `impresoras` VALUES ('1', 'Laser', 'Toner');

-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for monitores
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `monitores`;
CREATE TABLE `monitores` (
  `idreferencia` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tipom` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `tamano` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of monitores
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `monitores` VALUES ('3', 'LED', '21 plg');

-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for ordenadores
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `ordenadores`;
CREATE TABLE `ordenadores` (
  `idreferencia` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `placa` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `procesador` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `ram` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `disco` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of ordenadores
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `ordenadores` VALUES ('2', 'Asrock', 'Intel I3', '4G', '250 Gb');
```

Luego tenemos la consulta, De nivel algo complejo pero la voy a explicar detalladamente.

```
SELECT
FM.categoria,
FM.marca,
/*En el caso de cada categoria renombramos su campo para que todos salgan bajo un mismo nombre en este caso (P)*/
CASE 
    WHEN(FM.categoria='monitor') THEN MON.tipom
    WHEN(FM.categoria='impresora') THEN IMP.tipol
    WHEN(FM.categoria='ordenador') THEN ORD.placa
END as p,
/*Aplica lo mismo que el anterior para (P2)*/
CASE 
    WHEN(FM.categoria='monitor') THEN MON.tamano
    WHEN(FM.categoria='impresora') THEN IMP.consumible
    WHEN(FM.categoria='ordenador') THEN ORD.procesador
END as p2,

/*En el caso de monitores e impresoras no tienen los otros campos,asi que devolvemos una cadena vacia y ene l caso del ordenado el campo de la ram*/
CASE 
    WHEN(FM.categoria='monitor') THEN ''
    WHEN(FM.categoria='impresora') THEN ''
    WHEN(FM.categoria='ordenador') THEN ORD.ram
END as r,
/*Aplica lo mismo del caso anterior ahora  devolvemos el campo de disco*/
CASE 
    WHEN(FM.categoria='monitor') THEN ''
    WHEN(FM.categoria='impresora') THEN ''
    WHEN(FM.categoria='ordenador') THEN ORD.disco
END as d


FROM
fichamaterial AS FM
/*La sentencia LEF OUTER JOIN Busca el registro, si lo encuentra lo devuelve y si no toma valor vacio, En este caso Condicionamos el JOIN de la siguiente forma
 1- Si la categoria del equipo es monitor, Entonces el JOIN SERA entre fichamaterial y monitores, En caso negativo se devuelve NULL esto signifca que no hará join
 2- Si la categoria del equipo es impresora, Entonces el JOIN SERA entre fichamaterial e impresoras, En caso negativo se devuelve NULL esto signifca que no hará join
 3- Si la categoria del equipo es ordenador, Entonces el JOIN SERA entre fichamaterial y ordenadores, En caso negativo se devuelve NULL esto signifca que no hará join
*/
LEFT OUTER JOIN monitores AS MON ON FM.idreferencia=(CASE WHEN FM.categoria='monitor' THEN MON.idreferencia ELSE NULL END) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN impresoras AS IMP ON FM.idreferencia=(CASE WHEN FM.categoria='impresora' THEN IMP.idreferencia ELSE NULL END) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ordenadores AS ORD ON FM.idreferencia=(CASE WHEN FM.categoria='ordenador' THEN ORD.idreferencia ELSE NULL END)
```

El resultado final es el siguiente, Espero te ayude(Me pareció interesante el reto asi que como verás reconstruí toda la escena), Claro tambien puedes agregar mas left outer join si tienes otras categorias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En mi humilde opinión, aunque funcione de esta manera, me parece que el hecho de tener que hacer una consulta con tantos `CASE...` puede ser un indicador de que hay un error de diseño en la base de datos, creo que con un buen diseño se podrían obtener perfectamente los resultados deseados sin tener que dar tantas vueltas, pero se necesitaría un análisis más detallado de la situación y más detalles en la pregunta planteada. Aunque **este** problema quede resuelto, veremos volver al OP con **otro** problema en cuanto una pequeña modificación sea requerida...

Comment: @A.Cedano Totalmente de acuerdo, lo mas recomendable es tener un mejor diseño de la base de datos, sin embargo a veces no esta en nuestras manos, por ejemplo en donde trabajo hay una bd de un ERP del cual no puedo modificar nada, y tengo que adapatarme a las cosas poco optimas que tiene, tal vez a alguien con el mismo caso le pueda servir en algo.

Answer (score 0):

Ya que estas estudiando, creo recordar que la relacion que planteas se denomina IS-A (una tabla que contiene datos generales de una clasificacion y una tabla por cada clasificación)

Creo que lo que buscas es un **left-join**, que hace relación con la tabla que le indiques, y deja vacios (null) aquellos campos que no encuentra. Supongo (porque no lo has dicho) que todos los elementos de ficha material son de esos 3 tipos,y que todos los elementos de fichamaterial estan en alguna de las tablas.

Basandome en la estructura que plantea aquiles, he creado un ejemplo con esta consulta:

select f.*, i.tipol, i.consumible, m.tipom, m.tamano ,o.placa, o.procesador, o.ram , o.disco **from fichamaterial as f left join ordenadores as o on f.idreferencia=o.idreferencia left join impresoras as i on f.idreferencia=i.idreferencia left join monitores as m on f.idreferencia=m.idreferencia**;

con esto, me sale una tabla tal que asi:

```
+--------------+-----------+---------+-------+------------+-------+--------+----------+------------+------+--------+
| idreferencia | categoria | marca   | tipol | consumible | tipom | tamano | placa    | procesador | ram  | disco  |
+--------------+-----------+---------+-------+------------+-------+--------+----------+------------+------+--------+
|            2 | ordenador | DELL    | NULL  | NULL       | NULL  | NULL   | Asrock   | Intel I3   | 4G   | 250 Gb |
|            4 | ordenador | ASUS    | NULL  | NULL       | NULL  | NULL   | Gigabyte | Intel I7   | 32G  | 1Tb    |
|            1 | impresora | HP      | Laser | Toner      | NULL  | NULL   | NULL     | NULL       | NULL | NULL   |
|            3 | monitor   | Samsung | NULL  | NULL       | LED   | 21 plg | NULL     | NULL       | NULL | NULL   |
+--------------+-----------+---------+-------+------------+-------+--------+----------+------------+------+--------+
```

(he añadido el ordenador ASUS para que hubiera mas de un elemento de un tipo)

Ahora, puedes recorrer la tabla, y si el elemento es de una categoria muestras unos campos u otros.

Mira a ver si te sirve.